# Flagged a not relevant answer, but flag declined

Tags: discussion, support

I flagged this answer:

https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/195513/97780

as being spam ie not relevant but I am now warned it was declined as the moderators could not see anything wrong.

An answer that suggests that a soffit water leak (the original question) can be solved by the flux capacitor reaching 88mph (the flagged answer) and the moderators find that answer relevant?

I am confused.

Answer (score 4):

For the benefit of people that can't see it, that post reads:

> This tends to happen when the Flux Capacitor reaches 88 MPH.

I declined your flag because that post is not spam.

From the [Meta Stack Exchange FAQ on spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58032/146318):

> A post should be marked as spam only if it **advertises** a product, service, or similar **and is unsolicited or lacks disclosure**.

That post does neither of those things. Because of the penalties associated with spam flags -- the reputation hit and the blocks to prevent the user from posting again -- it's important to get it right. You should have used either the "not an answer" or "very low quality" flags instead.

Comment: When I see or hear spam - the first thing I get is Monty Python...

Comment: However, I had to pause and finally did not flag a post this morning - took a while for it to get removed though.